# MVC web service not rendering return data correctly

Tags: .net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to return data from a MVC webservice. I have `model`:

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        int itemInfoId;
        string itemDesc;
        int itemTypeId;
        DateTime itemDate;
        DateTime itemTime;
        float valueHigh;
        float valueLow;

internal List<Item> getItemFeed2(string userNo, string itemDateFrom, string itemDateTo, string itemTimeFrom, string itemTimeTo, float valueLowA, float valueLowB, float valueHighA, float valueHighB, string itemTypes)
        {   …
            List<Item> itemFeed = new List<Item>();

            try
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    itemFeed.Add(new Item
                    {

                        itemInfoId = (int)sdr.GetValue(0),
                        itemDesc = sdr.GetValue(4).ToString(),
                        itemTypeId = (int)sdr.GetValue(0),
                        itemDate = (DateTime)sdr.GetValue(5),
                        itemTime = (DateTime)sdr.GetValue(5), 
                        //valueHigh = (float)sdr.GetValue(7),
                        //valueLow = (float)sdr.GetValue(8)
                    });
                    i++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Error
            }
            finally
            {
                Shared.closeDbConnection(sqlCon);
            }
            return itemFeed;
        }
}
}
```

And `controller`:

```
public class ItemController : ApiController
{
public IEnumerable<Item> getItemFeed(string userNo, string itemDateFrom, string itemDateTo, string itemTimeFrom, string itemTimeTo, float valueLow, float valueHigh, string itemTypes)
{
    Item evObj = new Item();
    float valueLowA = valueLow - 10;
    float valueLowB = valueLow + 10;
    float valueHighA = valueHigh - 10;
    float valueHighB = valueHigh + 10;
    var itemFeed = evObj.getItemFeed2(userNo, itemDateFrom, itemDateTo, itemTimeFrom, itemTimeTo, valueLowA, valueLowB, valueHighA,valueHighB, itemTypes);

    return itemFeed;
}}
```

The `itemFeed` object when returning from model or controller shows `count=15` which is just right as there are 15 records but in browser windows the `xml` is just empty like this no data shown:

```
<ArrayOfItem xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject.Models">
<Item/>
<Item/>
<Item/>
<Item/>
<Item/>
<Item/>
<Item/>
<Item/>
<Item/>
<Item/>
<Item/>
</ArrayOfItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XmlSerialization cannot be done for private members. Change your fields into public fields or create a properties for them:

```
public int itemInfoId;
public string itemDesc;
public int itemTypeId;
public DateTime itemDate;
public DateTime itemTime;
public float valueHigh;
public float valueLow;
```